# Обособлять или нет оборот с "как"?

Tags: как, обороты-с-как, оборот-с-как, запятая-перед-как

делаю заголовок рассказа и тормознула. Как правильно?

> Люди как фальшивки. Фальшивки как люди.

или

> Люди, как фальшивки. Фальшивки, как люди.

Если мысленно доработать фразу, то будет: Люди ведут себя как фальшивки. Коварное "как" мне уже ночами снится. Я запуталась.

Answer (score 2):

1. Лучше выбрать вариант с обособлением:

***ЛЮди,** // **как фальшИвки**. **ФальшИвки**, // **как лЮди.***

Значение: **подобны фальшивкам.** Два ударения. По интонации (**наличие паузы**) это как бы аналог придаточного предложения: *Люди, / **которые подобны** фальшивкам.*

Сравнить (**название** фильма): *Год, **как жизнь**.*  *Год, **который** как жизнь.*

Сравнить: *Люди **как фальшИвки**. Фальшивки **как лЮди**.*

2. **В [Нацкорпусе](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CnoiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJwolCiMKA3JlcRIcChrQu9GO0LTQuCDQutCw0Log0LfQstC10YDQuDAA)** есть похожий вариант с повтором:

Николай Коляда. «Мы едем, едем, едем в далёкие края...» (1995)

*Крокодил в шампанском плавает. **Люди, как звери, звери, как люди...***

**Еще:** В. Я. Шишков. Ватага (1923)

*Люди, **как звери**, одни бегут, другие нагоняют.*

3. Вариант **с обособлением**  используется в том случае, если дальше следует **раскрытие темы**.

Вариант **без обособления** (сказуемое) — это чаще **законченное** суждение:

Екатерина Романова, Николай Романов. Дамы-козыри (2002)
*А вообще у нас и так все люди **как звери**.*

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта верны, но по разным значениям:

*Люди как фальшивки. Фальшивки как люди* — 'Люди есть фальшивки; фальшивки есть люди'. Оборот с *как* — сказуемое.

*Люди, как фальшивки. Фальшивки, как люди* — значение уподобления: 'Люди подобны фальшивкам; фальшивки подобны людям'. Не сказуемое, поэтому обособляем, чтобы расставить смысловые границы.

Об этом в [справочнике Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147) написано подробно. Читайте.